# How to have a link with diffrent variable for every loop?And how to get this variable for the link i point?

Tags: php, html

here is the code i wrote and my problem is that i want in every loop i want the diffrent email working as a link to another page and that page taking this email and do some things .Should i prepare soemhow the link so the user_profile.php page can get the email?

```
</tr>
        <?php foreach( $results as $row )
            {
                $email = $row['email'];
                echo "<tr><td>";
                    echo $row['id'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $email;
                        echo "</td><td>";
                    echo  $row['name'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['surname'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['phone'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['admin'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['created_at'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
            1.  //echo "<a href =user_profile.php?email=$email </a>";
            2.  //echo href="user_profile.php?email=$row['email'];
            3.  //<li><a href="user_profile.php?email=<?php echo $email; "><?php echo $email; </a></li>
            4.  //<li><a href="user_profile.php?email=$email";><?php echo $email; </a></li>
                    echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: `href="user_profile.php?email=whatever_you_want"`

Comment: Edit:Yes that was my mistake i wanted to show how to have a href link like the commented out lines but inside the php .

Comment: @user2913267 If you're looking for how to do that with an echo, I've added it to my answer here.

Comment: Im not sure if im getting right but i changed my code above and still cant have each email pointing to user_profile.php with email included .Ive added some comments to my code above so please check it and help me.

Comment: Your html and php are all over the place in your latest edits. #1 won't work because you didn't put quotes around the url and didn't close the opening a tag or provide link text. #2 won't work because you didn't put quotes around the first part of the string or close the double quotes. #3 should work but you need to close the php block first like ?> then open it after the line. #4 you have the php variable in the html of the a tag and a semi-colon in there too, then you open a php block to echo the email but you don't close the block, you just go right back into the html.

Comment: @user2913267 See my last update with your whole block of code.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
<li><a href="user_profile.php"><?php echo $email; ?></a></li>
```

To

```
 <li><a href="user_profile.php?email=<?php echo $email; ?>"><?php echo $email; ?></a></li>
```

To do that in PHP with echo it would look like this:

```
echo '<li><a href="user_profile.php?email='.$email.'">'.$email.'</a></li>';
```

Then on the user_profile.php page you can grab the email like this:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

Edit: I fixed a small mistake and cleaned up a bit. Also, the code your shared will produce an error since you put the html in a php code block. You'll want to either adjust the code to echo the link or close the php bock to echo the link and start a new block for the rest.

Edit Edit: If the user is supplying the email, be sure to validate the email, and you should probably also escape the output to be sure that the user can't inject and code or html into the link, especially on the user_profile.php page where you're getting the email from the url. In that case, you should echo the email address like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($email);
```

See these links (especially the second one) for explanations.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Edit Edit Edit:

I've just updated your code as a whole because there were a lot of problems in the edit that you added for me.

```
</tr>
    <?php foreach( $results as $row )
        {
            $email = $row['email'];
            echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $row['id'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                echo $email;
                    echo "</td><td>";
                echo  $row['name'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['surname'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['phone'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['admin'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['created_at'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                echo '<li><a href="user_profile.php?email='.$email.'">'.$email.'</a></li>';

                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
```